# Can´t load image from package

Tags: java, image, maven, resources, package

My problem is that I can´t load an image from an subpackage in my java project with maven.

[This is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieg9j.png)

I tryed some different code snippets but always get a Nullpointer exception.

I tryed:

```
Image image = new Image("/frontend/pictures/logo.png");
Image image = new Image("frontend/pictures/logo.png");
Image image = new Image("pictures/logo.png");
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("frontend/pictures/logo.png").toString());
```

In an other Project it works fine for me but now I don´t know what I do wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What package is the Image class in that has args for the constructor?

Comment: Which `Image` class are you using here?  `java.awt.Image` only has a no-args constructor, and it is the only `Image` class that >>Java<< defines.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to say that I use javafx.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice image loading method I've created using ImageIcons:

```
public Image img(String path) {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(path);
    return icon.getImage();
}
```

Then when you wish to load an image, just use:

```
Image image = img("frontend/pictures/logo.png")
```

and this should work.
Note that if you want to use a runnable JAR, you'll have to use this implementation:

```
static Image setImage(String path) {
    Image tmp = null;
    try {
        tmp = ImageIO.read(/*Class name*/.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

and feed in:

```
Image image = setImage("/org/.../logo.png");
```

with your image placed in some subfolder inside the org folder of the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad that I forgot to say that I working with JavaFX.
But I fixed my Problem.

I add the picture dir as ressource folder and then:

```
Image img = new Image(getClass.getRessource("/logo.png").toString);
```

Thanks for your help.